# Getting state, getters, actions of vuex module in vue component

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.4, vuex

I tried the syntax given in vuex doc.

store.state.a // -> moduleA's state
store.state.b // -> moduleB's state

**app.js**

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */
Vue.component('task-index', require('./components/TaskList.vue'));
Vue.component('task-show', require('./components/TaskShow.vue'));
Vue.component('note-index', require('./components/NoteList.vue'));
Vue.component('note-show', require('./components/NoteShow.vue'));

const notes = {
    state: {
        edit: false,
        list:[],
        note: { 
            note : '',
            id : ''
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        SET_EDIT: (state, data) => {
            state.edit = data
        },
        SET_LIST: (state, data) => {
            state.list = data
        },
        SET_NOTE: (state, data) => {
            state.note.id = data.id;
            state.note.note = data.note;
        },
        SET_EMPTY: (state) => {
            state.note.note  = '';
        }      
    },
    getters: {
        noteCount: (state) => state.list.length
    },
    actions : {
        getNote: ({commit,state}) => {
            axios.get('/api/note/list')
            .then((response) => {
                commit('SET_LIST', response.data);
                commit('SET_EDIT',false);
                commit('SET_EMPTY');
            })
        },
    }
};

const tasks = {
    state: {
        edit: false,
        list:[],
        task: { 
            body : '',
            id : ''
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        SET_EDIT: (state, data) => {
            state.edit = data
        },
        SET_LIST: (state, data) => {
            state.list = data
        },
        SET_TASK: (state, data) => {
            state.task.id = data.id;
            state.task.body = data.body;
        },
        SET_EMPTY: (state) => {
            state.task.body  = '';
        }      
    },
    getters: {
        taskCount: (state) => state.list.length
    },
    actions : {
        getTask: ({commit,state}) => {
            axios.get('/api/task/list')
            .then((response) => {
                commit('SET_LIST', response.data);
                commit('SET_EDIT',false);
                commit('SET_EMPTY');
            })
        },
    }
};

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules : {
        task : tasks,
        note : notes
    }
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store
});
```

**TaskList.vue**

```
<template>
    <div >
        <h4>{{count}} Task(s)</h4>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item" v-for="item in list">
                {{item.body}}
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" @click="showTask(item.id)">Edit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" @click="deleteTask(item.id)">Delete</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default{
    computed :{
        list() {
            return this.$store.state.task.list; 
        },
        count(){
            return this.$store.getters.taskCount;            
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.$store.dispatch('getTask');
    },
    methods : {

        showTask: function(id){
            axios.get('/api/task/'+ id)
            .then(response => {
                this.$store.commit('SET_TASK',response.data);
                this.$store.commit('SET_EDIT',true);
            });
        },
        deleteTask: function(id){
            axios.delete('/api/task/delete/' + id)
            this.$store.dispatch('getTask');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I'am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'task' of undefined " in this line of code 'return this.$store.state.task.list;'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

acoording to [documentation](http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html) of vuex

> By default, actions, mutations and getters inside modules are still
>   registered under the global namespace

so you can only use getters in vuex root context.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the state you're trying to retrieve doesn't match the structure of your state:

```
state: {
    edit: false,
    list:[],
    note: { 
        note : '',
        id : ''
    }
},
```

If you change `this.$store.state.task.list` to `this.$store.state.list` then you should be all patched up.

Comment: task is the module thal list belongs to.After few corrections now I'am able to get the state using this.$store.state.task.list.But  when i use the same syntax for gettters ie, 'return this.$store.getters.task.taskCount;'  error shown is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'taskCount' of undefined".but everything is ok when i code like this 'return this.$store.getters.taskCount;'.

Comment: Well, that's basically showing the same thing I've outlined above. There seems to be a disconnect between how you expect your store to be structured and how it actually is structured. Are you using the Vue.js Devtools plugin for Chrome? That may help you sort out these types of problems easier.

Comment: Yeah, I'am using Vue.js Devtools

Comment: I am having the exact same issue with a modules getters not being accessible via $store.getters.module.getX. have you found out why?