# Cannot get vuex state in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to get user data once they logged in but it returns `Object` instead of array of user.

## Code

**App.js (main component)**

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                user: ''
            }
        },
        computed : {
            isLoggedIn() {
                return this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn
            }
        },
        methods: {
            logout: function () {
                this.$store.dispatch('logout')
                .then(() => {
                    this.$router.push({name: 'home'})
                })
            }
        },
        created: function () {
            this.user = this.$store.getters.loggedUser
            console.log('user data', this.$store.getters.loggedUser) //returns Object
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'
Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    status: '',
    token: localStorage.getItem('access_token') || '',
    user : {}
  },
  mutations: {
    auth_request(state){
        state.status = 'loading'
      },
      auth_success(state, token, user){
        state.status = 'success'
        state.token = token
        state.user = user
      },
      auth_error(state){
        state.status = 'error'
      },
      logout(state){
        state.status = ''
        state.token = ''
      },
  },
  actions: {
    login({commit}, user){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          commit('auth_request')
          axios({url: '/api/auth/login', data: user, method: 'POST' })
          .then(resp => {
            const token = resp.data.access_token
            const user = resp.data.user
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', token)
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =  'Bearer ' + token
            commit('auth_success', token, user)
            resolve(resp)
          })
          .catch(err => {
            commit('auth_error')
            localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
            reject(err)
          })
        })
    },
    register({commit}, user){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          commit('auth_request')
          axios({url: 'api/auth/register', data: user, method: 'POST' })
          .then(resp => {
            console.log('register data', resp);
            const token = resp.data.access_token
            const user = resp.data.user
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', token)
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =  'Bearer ' + token
            commit('auth_success', token, user)
            resolve(resp)
          })
          .catch(err => {
            commit('auth_error', err)
            localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
            reject(err)
          })
        })
      },
      logout({commit}){
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + this.state.token
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios({url: 'api/auth/logout', method: 'POST' })
          .then(resp => {
            commit('logout')
            localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
            localStorage.removeItem('token_type')
            delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']
            resolve()
          })
          .catch(err => {
            commit('logout')
            localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
            localStorage.removeItem('token_type')
            delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']
            reject(err)
          })
        })
      }
  },
  getters: {
    isLoggedIn: state => !!state.token,
    authStatus: state => state.status,
    loggedUser: state => state.user,
  }
});

export default store;
```

> **Note:** Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42603732/8490993) I've added `loggedUser: state => state.user,` to my `getters` but all i'm getting is object and nothing
>   about user data.

## Screenshot

[image: one]

## Question

How can I get my user data in my component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

Well as I couldn't get my user info from vuex state i decided to limit my user data from backend and store them in localStorage that way i can get my user data from storage instead of vuex.

## Code

`store.js`

```
login({commit}, user){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        commit('auth_request')
        axios({url: '/api/auth/login', data: user, method: 'POST' })
        .then(resp => {
        console.log(resp)
        const token = resp.data.access_token
        const user = resp.data.user
        console.log(user)
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', token)
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user)) // added this line
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =  'Bearer ' + token
        commit('auth_success', token, user)
        resolve(resp)
        })
        .catch(err => {
        commit('auth_error')
        localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
        localStorage.removeItem('user')
        reject(err)
        })
    })
},
```

`App.vue (main component)`

I removed `created()` function and added `mounted()` function

```
mounted() {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    const state = user
        ? { status: { loggedIn: true }, user }
        : { status: {}, user: null };
        if(user){
            this.user = user.name
        } else {
            console.log('nothing')
        }
}
```

this way i don't have any error not when there is visitor, nor when is logged user. Also I can get my user name immediately after they've logged in.

Hope it can be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it simply inside of `value`?

`this.user.value`

Comment: in which part?!

Comment: After `this.user = this.$store.getters.loggedUser`

Comment: In the console you screenshot it clearly shows a value key. Have you tried expanding it

Comment: here is screenshot of that value you've mentioned https://ibb.co/6nYkzNZ

Comment: Log the respsone  `resp.data.user` and `resp.data`. Would be interesting to see what gets sent

Comment: When do you call the login action?

Comment: when i try to login (login.vue)

Comment: Right you are trying to get the data too soon. The created hook probably runs before the action has happened. You should either hydrate your store before you mount the app or add some kind of watcher and wait for the store to be populated

Comment: would you give me a sample?

Comment: OK I will post something later.

Answer (score 0):

You should get user info after user logging not when App component is created. Because when App component is created you didn't log in.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205207/discussion-on-answer-by-luckytuvshee-cannot-get-vuex-state-in-vue-component).

Comment: I tried(declare variable initial value with empty object {} and print in created() of app component) and it shows exactly like yours. So the problem is you are calling the getter before the getter is set.